# Meteor Handlebars: value in array in {{#each}} block

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm new to Meteor/Handlebars using the meteor package https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/plans-stripe which contains these two helpers.

```
AppPlans.listDefined() - to get the list of all our plans 
 - ["free", "monthly", "yearly"]

AppPlans.get() - to see which plan the user currently has. 
 - ["free"]
```

And https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers which has this useful helper:

```
{{$eq a b}} if a equals b then return true
```

I'm displaying the plans in my HTML like so:

```
{{#each AppPlans.listDefined}}

   <strong>{{this}}</strong>

{{/each}}
```

But I'd like to do is something like this; which doesn't work

```
{{#each AppPlans.listDefined}}
   {{#if $eq AppPlans.listDefined AppPlans.get}}
        <strong>{{this}}</strong>
   {{else}}
      <span>{{this}}</span>
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently comparing two arrays, not two scalars. `$eq` is not going to work. Since you're looping over the plans you actually want to see if the current (scalar) plan `this` is in the *array* of plans the current user has.

```
{{#each AppPlans.listDefined}}
   {{#if $inArray this AppPlans.get}}
        <strong>{{this}}</strong>
   {{else}}
      <span>{{this}}</span>
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Then an `$inArray` helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('$inArray',function(s,a){
  return a.indexOf(s) > -1;
});
```